# How to link a css file with the Slim templating engine?

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

i am working on a little Sinatra/Slim project, and i want to include a css file. All works fine except that.

Here is my project "tree":

```
├── essai.rb
    └── views
        ├── form.slim
        └── style.css
```

And this is the head of form.slim:

```
html

head

    title Vote
    link href="style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
```

I've tried `"views/style.css"`, `"../style.css"`,...etc. but Rake log the error `"GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404`. I know i have no routes for the css in sinatra, but i suppose there is a trick to avoid that... i hope :D

And i tried like i can see on the slim example page: `file_path("style.css")` but, i have a `undefined method 'file_path'` error, i guess because its a ruby function passed in args in the slim example.

Could someone tell me how can i do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinatra expects your css files files to reside in the `public` directory, not within the `views` directory by default.

So your project tree should look more like this.

```
/essai.rb
/views
      /form.slim
/public
      /css
          /style.css
```

Then you should be able to access it with your existing slim template.

Comment: Ok, so simple... I was searching mostly in the Slim doc, and i didnt notice the "static file" section in the Sinatra Readme. Thanks!

Comment: it would help if you add a more complete answer like what the head should include

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the accepted answer. However, his answer will be incomplete to those new to Sinatra. Yes you have to put your CSS file in **public/css/**

The code in your head should be

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" type="text/css"
```

Those new to Sinatra take note that your CSS file name can be anything, such as styles.css, app.css, main.css or whatever.

Here is a screenshot of my own project

[image]

Comment: your example has 'rel' attribute twice.